# count column info once per user in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Ive got tracking data that shows how often a person is viewing a page.  If the person is substituting for another area then both their main position and substitute position get counted.
I'd like to just count one of their positions and not the other.

check out this dataframe:

```
df =

index      name             Area       views      date    report view

1          Jack Johnson     North        5        5/12     first page
2          Jack Johnson     West         5        5/12     first page
3          Tim Peters       South        10       1/1      first page
4          Jenny Looks      East         2        2/13     first page
5          Jenny Looks      East         5        6/7      first page
6          Jenny Looks      East         5        6/7      second page
```

```
final_df =
## the area dropped doesnt matter as long as I can confirm that the dates, views, and report view were the same

index      name             Area       views      date     report view

1          Jack Johnson     North        5        5/12     first page
2          Tim Peters       South        10       1/1      first page
3          Jenny Looks      East         2        2/13     first page
4          Jenny Looks      East         5        6/7      first page
5          Jenny Looks      East         5        6/7      second page (safe because diff page)
```

I've used df.loc[(df['name'] == 'Jack Johnson') & df['Area'] == 'North') and that works, but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to go though the whole dataframe to test if an area comes up with multiple values for the person then make it so only 1 is counted.  This would help avoid me looking though the entire dataset for same people but with having different areas.

Thank you !

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['name', 'date'])`

Comment: ah thanks for this.. I actaully went back and just ran this and noticed something that I missed and that was the user is tracked on which page they view too! so its ok if the user views  different pages on the same day as long as their 'Area' is the same and their name is the same. I updated my question.  With drop duplicates by date it drops those duplicate dates.  Let me know if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this should solve your problem,

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=["name","date","report view"])
```

For more information about `.drop_duplicates()`visit [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

Answer (score 1):

include `'report view'` to the subset list

```
final_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['name', 'date', 'report view'])
```

This will drop records that have the same `name`, `date` and `report view`.

Answer (score 1):

So if it has to be the same area, date, name, and different report view I will do similar as was written in the comment:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['name', 'date','report view'])
```